# c++ Trie data structure implementation clarifications

Tags: c++

The current code is an implementation of the [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure in C++.

For me, in the memory, a Trie contains two items, a pointer to a table of Tries and a bool.

The question is where a single character is stored in memory. if a `node` contains a `node*` and a `bool`?

```
 class Trie {
    public:
        bool isLeaf;
        Trie* character[CHAR_SIZE];
    
        //contructor
        Trie() {
            this->isLeaf = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_SIZE; i++) {
                this->character[i] = nullptr;
            }
        }
    };
    void insert(string);
        bool deletion(Trie*&, string);
        bool search(string);
        bool haveChildren(Trie const*);
```

Comment: Data are stored in the formed tree. To "retrieve" a word, you need to navigate the tree (and check final `isLeaf == true`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm talking about a single character in memory. if a node contain a node * and a bool , where is the character is stored ?

Comment: For `"hello"` , you would have `character['h']->character['e']->character['l']->character['l']->character['o']->isLeaf`. If there is `nullptr` in the chain, or `isLeaf` is false, the word is not in the trie.

Comment: The character is stored implicitly, via the index to the array. To know if the string "a" exists, you will test character['a'].isLeaf. There is no need to say that character['a'].code = 'a'.

Comment: @Jarod42 I cannot fathom how to interpret character['h'] , what is 'h' here? if a character is a table, then the indexes are going from zero to size of the table

Comment: @MakhloufGHARBI What's `CHAR_SIZE` in your context actually?

Comment: `'h'` is the character `'h'` (its ascii value is 104). `character` is an array containing children for the next character. child is `nullptr` when next letter is absent. `isLeaf` is a flag to know is the current letter/node is the end of the word.

Comment: You can see `Trie* character[CHAR_SIZE];` as `std::map<char, Trie*>` (and contrary to the `std::map`, the key doesn't need to be stored in structure).

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any characters stored anywhere. You have an array of Trie objects called 'character' but no characters.

I do not know the Trie data structure but you probably want

```
class Trie {
    public:
        bool isLeaf;
        char ch;  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<============
        Trie* character[CHAR_SIZE];
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand because, without the `char ch` , the structure is working correctly. 
From what I can understand now, when we store a character, we just create a node, without an explicit store. if the pointer to this node is not null, then we can consider that the character is stored

Comment: @MakhloufGHARBI Without `ch` you have a tree structure, but it contains no useful information about what the nodes represent. You can traverse it manipulate it and do all sorts of things with it, but you cannot do the most important: recreate the recreate the information  the Trie is supposed to contain.

Comment: @MakhloufGHARBI but you were asking 'where is the character', answer - nowhere. You just have a tree of voids

Comment: @pm100 The Trie holds a character value by its position in the parent Trie's `character` table.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have set up your `Trie` class, a `Trie` object represents a character by its position in its parent's `character` table. So a single character `x` would be represented by:

- a root `Trie` object with `isLeaf = false` with all of `character` being null pointers, except for `character[ 'x' ]` pointing to...
- a `Trie` object with `isLeaf = true`.

Needless to say that this is a bit less than optimal. An ideal structure would need only one `Trie` object for the single character case. But given your existing code and barring major refactoring, that is how a single character would be represented by your `Trie`.

---

If you are looking at rather sparse data, you could optimize your `Trie` to store unabiguous sequences in the object. So if you have `"foo"` and `"fornicitialicious"`, you would have a root `Trie` that stores `"fo"` and two pointers, one to a leaf `Trie` storing `"o"` and one to a leaf `Trie` storing `"rnicitialicious"`. That way, a single character `'x'` would be a single (leaf) `Trie` storing `"x"`.